# GetDabataseLocked + NPE in AlarmManager

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, alarmmanager

I have an AlarmManager that run each day at the same hour.
The aim of the alarm is synchronize the app between sqlite and MySQL.

The thing is when I work with my sqlite db, I use :

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
```

This line gives me a NPE probably because this is null ( Because the method is called outside of the application)

How could I write this line to be context independent?

Answer (score 0):

The NPE in `getDatabaseLocked()` is because you passed a `null` for a `Context` to the `SQLiteOpenHelper` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

## Issue is

```
The Context that you are passing to the SQLiteOpenHelper constructor is null.
```

## solution

pass application context.make a java class and extends it with application class and return context.also add this class to your manifest  in application tag like:

```
android:name="com.yourpkgname.yourclassname"
```